# PHP - How can i maintain value of a select element after a postback?

Tags: php, postback

I currently have this select:

```
<select name="state" id="state" selected="<?php echo $state; ?>">
        <option value="--">--</option>
        <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
        <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
        <option value="NT">NT</option>
</select>
```

this is the php related to $state:

```
<?php 
    $state = "";
    $state = $_POST["state"];
?>
```

since i am not running any validation on it i simply want to retain its value after postback.

Comment: In the PHP, you overwrite `$state` from an empty variable to the POST-value, so the first line there actually does nothing useful at all. You should however check if the POST-value is set, to avoid *Undefined index* notices. Further, there is no `selected` in the `<select>` tag, that's an attribute of the `<option>` tag. You could do `<option value="ACT" <?php echo (isset($_POST['state']) && $_POST['state'] == "ACT") ? "selected " : ""; ?>>ACT</option>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options are selectable...

Try this:

```
<select name="state" id="state">
    <option value="--">--</option>
    <option value="ACT"<?php if ($state=="ACT"){echo " selected";} ?>>ACT</option>
    <option value="NSW"<?php if ($state=="NSW"){echo " selected";} ?>>NSW</option>
    <option value="NT"<?php if ($state=="NT"){echo " selected";} ?>>NT</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to

```
<select name="state" id="state" selected="<?php echo $state; ?>">
        <option value="--"<?php echo ($state=='')?" selected":""?>>--</option>
        <option value="ACT"<?php echo ($state=='ACT')?" selected":""?><>ACT</option>
        <option value="NSW"<?php echo ($state=='NSW')?" selected":""?>>NSW</option>
        <option value="NT"<?php echo ($state=='NT')?" selected":""?>>NT</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple condition on your option tag will do...

You just need to set `selected` on the option tag if it is selected.

```
<select name="state" id="state" selected="<?php echo $state; ?>">
    <option value="--">--</option>
    <option <?php if($state == "ACT") echo "selected"; ?> value="ACT">ACT</option>
    <option <?php if($state == "NSW") echo "selected"; ?> value="NSW">NSW</option>
    <option <?php if($state == "NT") echo "selected"; ?>  value="NT">NT</option>
</select>
```